# Mapstruct: How to default a target String to Empty String when the Source is Null (Both fields have the same name and type) Java / Spring

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have two Objects Source and Target both with the same field names and types.

If a source field is null I would like the target to be "" (Empty String)

My Interface mapping looks like this (This is just two field, I have many)

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT)
public interface MyMapper {

@Mappings({
    @Mapping(target="medium", defaultExpression="java(\"\")"),
    @Mapping(target="origin", defaultExpression="java(\"\")")
 }) 
public Target mapFrom(Source source)
```

If the Source has a value it should be copied across, if it is null in the source it should be "" in the target.

Mapstruct-1.3.0 seems to just keep everything null.

Any Idea? I would like default to be empty String for everything

Comment: Little offtopic from me: you can set default componentModel to "spring" for all of your mappers, hence no need to explicitly set it in `@Mapper` annotation. Refer to http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#configuration-options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy` (as part of the `Mapper` annotation) for defining how null properties are to be mapped.

See [NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.html#SET_TO_DEFAULT](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.html#SET_TO_DEFAULT)

The default value for `String` is `""`. You don't need to define it explicitly.

So, your mapper can simply look like this:

```
@Mapper(
    componentModel = "spring", 
    nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT, 
    nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT
)
public interface MyMapper {

    public Target mapFrom(Source source);

}
```

Comment: This strategy is different from [the one OP is using](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/api/org/mapstruct/NullValueMappingStrategy.html#RETURN_DEFAULT), but the default value for `String` may be the same.

Comment: Exactly. `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy` is the one the OP is looking for.

Comment: So in code is this not what I am doing?


    `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT)`


as currently I still get Null values on the target

Comment: `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy` != `NullValueMappingStrategy`

Comment: @Michael Yes it does thanks a stack, Getting somewhat confused with all the variations

Comment: Are you sure it works: NullvalueMappingstrategie applies to the property containing bean you map. NullvaluePropertyMapping to the properties in update methods. If you need this or property, use @Mapping#defaultValue.

Comment: I added some material to our FAQ on the MapStruct site: http://mapstruct.org/faq/#How-do-I-handle-null-properties-in-the-source-bean

Comment: This is only applicable for update methods with  `@MappingTarget` annotation

Answer (score 0):

When your Source object has the **same** fields as Target object and when you want to manage all Source **null** values (e.g. for String) to became an **empty String** ("") in the Target object, you could create mapper interface from [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) library as below:

#### Step 1:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SourceToTargetMapper {

  Target map(Source source);

  @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT)
  void update(Source source, @MappingTarget Target target);
}
```

The whole trick is to define `nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT` but you cannot define it in @Mapper annotation. Instead of that you had to place it as parameter in @BeanMapping annotation for `update()` method.
You can read more about this in [MapStruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-result-for-null-properties).

#### Step 2:

Therefore you had to do one more operation in your code and use just implemented 'update()' method:

```java
@Component
public class ClassThatUsingMapper {

  private final SourceToTargetMapper mapper;

  public Target someMethodToMapObjects(Source source) {
    Target target = mapper.map(source);
    mapper.update(source, target)

    return target;
  }
}
```

All *null to empty String process* takes place under `mapper.update(source, target)` method. After run `mvn clean install` for your project, you can check how it looks and how it works in `target/generated-sources/annotations/...../SourceToTargetMapperImpl.java` file.